# Gwt add module (module selection)

Tags: gwt

Where should I put my *.gwt.xml file, so the gwt module selection will find it? I've tried to put it directly in the project but it's not working.
And also, it is the same .gwt.xml find that I find in the main project, in the src directory?

(I'm using libgdx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about libgdx but the module xml is placed under the module package. So if the package is com.myApp for example you just put the xml there.

Answer (score 2):

Read here about [GWT Project Organization](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html).

Read about **Loading modules** mentioned in above link.

***Module XML files should reside in your project's root package.***

Snapshot of my sample GWT project

[image]